# How can I solve the connection problem during npm install behind a proxy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, proxy, electron

I followed the instruction:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app

I typed `mkdir`, `cd` and `npm init`. They all worked well. One file named `package.json` appeared.

Then I typed `npm install --save-dev electron`. Some error occured.

```
lala@ubu:~/projects/electron/my-app 17:20:34
$ npm install --save-dev electron

> core-js@3.6.4 postinstall /home/lala/projects/electron/my-app/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> electron@8.0.0 postinstall /home/lala/projects/electron/my-app/node_modules/electron
> node install.js

(node:5950) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RequestError: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.250.177.223:443
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/lala/projects/electron/my-app/node_modules/got/source/request-as-event-emitter.js:178:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:228:7)
    at ClientRequest.origin.emit (/home/lala/projects/electron/my-app/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/source/index.js:37:11)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:406:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
(node:5950) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:5950) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN my-app@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN my-app@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ electron@8.0.0
added 85 packages from 91 contributors and audited 102 packages in 87.419s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

After executing the above instructions, one folder `node_modules` and one file `package-lock.json` appeared.

It seemed that I had successfully installed the dependencies. But why one connection error occured?

I can not access `github.com(13.250.177.223)` directly, but my proxy works.

I have configured proxy as following, but the connection error still exists.

My ~/.bashrc

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8123/
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8123/
export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8123/
export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8123/
```

```
$ cat ~/.npmrc 
proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8123/
http-proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8123/
https-proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8123/
noproxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,192.168.,10.
strict-ssl=false
```

node v12.14.1 npm v6.13.7

How can I reduce the error?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Problem solved at https://v2ex.com/t/642210.

Answer (score 34):

Try this solution for installing electron node module from behind proxy.

```
npx cross-env ELECTRON_GET_USE_PROXY=true GLOBAL_AGENT_HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@host:8080 npm install -D electron@latest
```

- here `username:password` is your network username and password if required.
- here `host:8080` is your proxy server host name and port number.
- `cross-env` is another node module to support command line variables (optional).

Comment: We can check this gh comment for more info, about installing electorn behind proxy.  https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20739#issuecomment-577981558

Comment: `npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/cross-env failed, reason: connect ENETUNREACH 104.16.16.35:443` - this is what I get

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
npx cross-env ELECTRON_GET_USE_PROXY=true GLOBAL_AGENT_HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:3128 npm install electron
```

Sauce: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20739#issuecomment-577981558